# Why pyodbc executemany autocommits each execute call?

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, sap-iq

Sybase IQ:
I set `autocommit = False` but executemany still autocommits each insert I make.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Insert                                                   |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
| INSERT INTO Position.RC_Balance_Cash_2018_10 (Account,   |
| SubAccount,                                              |
| AccountSubType,                                          |
| AsOfDateTime,                                            |
| AccountingDate,                                          |
| OTE,                                                     |
| Balance,                                                 |
| CurrencyISO,                                             |
| TDSDBasis,                                               |
| OMV,                                                     |
| CompareType,                                             |
| RecID,                                                   |
| TotalEquity,                                             |
| Side,                                                    |
| Client) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)           |
+----------------------------------------------------------+

conn= pyodbc.connect(connStr, autocommit=False)
#conn.set_attr(pyodbc.SQL_ATTR_TXN_ISOLATION, pyodbc.SQL_TXN_SERIALIZABLE)
conn.autocommit = False 
cur= conn.cursor()

cur.fast_executemany = True
data = rows[total:][:chunk]

cur.executemany(sql, data )
```

I even tried to rollback explicitly without luck:

```
cur.execute("ROLLBACK")
#or
conn.rollback()
```

Comment: If you are actually creating your connection with a context manager (`with` block) then see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/43).

Comment: Unable to reproduce your issue using SQL Server. [This code](https://pastebin.com/uMg2SD67) works correctly.

Comment: @GordThompson I use Sybase IQ

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if you use `cur.fast_executemany = False` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson Still autocommiting. Same code works fine with Vertica and SQL Server.

Comment: An [ODBC trace log](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log) might help shed some light on what the Sybase IQ driver is doing.

Comment: @GordThompson i'm on linux

Comment: That wiki page has [instructions for Linux](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log#linux), too.